# How to save many pdf files into a folder in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have many pdf files in my database and I want to store them in a folder based on priority. When I use the code below I am unable to save all files; it just saves one file. :(

```
Declare 
            @File_Path_1 VARBINARY(MAX),
            @FileName_1 VARCHAR(MAX),
            @Timestamp_1 varchar(max),
            @objectToken_1 int

DECLARE cFiles CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT request_number from data where priority=1
OPEN cFiles

FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles INTO @FileName_1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
   SET @FileName_1 = @FileName_1
    set @Timestamp_1='c:\Dump\1.pdf'
    EXEC sp_oacreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken_1 OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_oasetproperty @objecttoken_1, 'type', 1
    EXEC sp_oamethod @objecttoken_1,'open'
    EXEC sp_oamethod @objecttoken_1,'Write',Null,@File_Path_1
    EXEC sp_oamethod @objecttoken_1,'Savetofile',Null,@Timestamp_1,2
    EXEC sp_oamethod @objecttoken_1,'Close'
    EXEC sp_oamethod @objecttoken_1,'open'

    FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles INTO @FileName_1
END

CLOSE cFiles
DEALLOCATE cFiles
```

the code above fetches me just one record can any one please help in

Comment: Does this query: `SELECT request_number from data where priority=1` get you a list of all the files you want to output?

Comment: Are you sure you are not just writing to  'c:\Dump\1.pdf' many times?

Comment: @GoatCO yes it lists the files present in the database

Comment: @Blam yes but how do I make it dynamic :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SOURCEPATH VARBINARY(MAX),
@DESTPATH VARCHAR(MAX),
@ObjectToken INT,
@Request_Number varchar(30)

DECLARE PDFPATH CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT ID from Table 
OPEN PDFPATH
FETCH NEXT FROM PDFPATH INTO @SOURCEPATH, @Request_Number 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @DESTPATH = 'C:\path' + CAST(@Request_Number AS varchar) + '.pdf'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @SOURCEPATH
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @DESTPATH, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken

FETCH NEXT FROM PDFPATH INTO @SOURCEPATH, @Request_Number
END
```

I Hope this snippet helps people who are in need :) Thank you all for helping me :)

Comment: 1) you should mention that you copied this code from http://heidibrebels.be/blog/archives/2011/save-image-sql-server-file-sql  and 2) you should have copied all of it including the final CLOSE and DEALLOCATE statements  and 3) your SELECT statement does not request the source data.  This is not much better code than what the original question has.

Comment: The link for the blog has now [changed](http://heidibrebels.be/blogpost.php?p=14)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are not dynamically creating the filename:

`set @Timestamp_1='c:\Dump\1.pdf'`

should be something like:

`set @Timestamp_1='c:\Dump\' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @FileName_1) + '.pdf'`

And you don't seem to be getting the source data to write out; @File_Path_1 is never set.  You need to add a field to the SELECT list and add the @File_Path_1 variable to the FETCH statement.

Also, this line doesn't do anything:

`SET @FileName_1 = @FileName_1`